# Having a react jsx component in state, Best practice

Tags: reactjs

Is it appropriate to have a jsx component in your state?

```
const [personalDetailsArray, setPersonalDetailsArray] = useState([
<PersonalDetails key={id}/>]);
```

For example, (see above) having a state array that can update and help you render components as your state changes.

Comment: Why do you need to put it in a state variable?

Comment: That's how I am adding components to the view. After an onClick event, the state array is concatenated with a similar <PersonalDetails  key={id}/> JSX component.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea to store your dynamic components on state, instead you can use function to render dynamically a component depending on your state/props data.

You can do it like this

```
const YourComponent = (props)=>{
  const [personalDetailsArray, setPersonalDetailsArray] = useState([
    ]);

  const getDynamicComponet= (id)=>{

    switch (id){

      case id ===  'personalDetails': 
        return <PersonalDetails key={ id } />
      case id  === 'component_1':
        retrun ...
      case ...

    }
  }

  const id = 'personalDetails'// or from props , or from state 
  return (
    getDynamicComponent(id)
  )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, state should rather be used for storing the state of data in your app.

Then use something like map on the data to return the relevant UI components.

E.g.

```
const [personalDetails, setPersonalDetails] = useState([<your data for personal details>]);

return personalDetails.map(personalDetail=><PersonalDetails key={personalDetail.id}/>)
```

By doing this way you make it easier for React to compare changes to state (as you're only storing the data now). Moreover the code is better decoupled with rendering and data split out.

More information can be [found here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I guess the question has probably been asked before.